# link error- Qt Creator OpenCV Ubuntu

Tags: c++, opencv

I am currently having a link error with Qt.
I cant compile my code since i got the error message:

```
 error: undefined reference to `cv::imread(cv::String const&, int)'
```

Heres the content of my .pro

```
QT       += core

QT       -= gui

TARGET = edge_detection
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp


INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/opencv
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/opencv2
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib
LIBS += -lopencv_core
LIBS += -lopencv_imgproc
LIBS += -lopencv_highgui
```

Heres my simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>


int main(){

    cv::Mat img;

    img=cv::imread("/home/cgross/Downloads/2.jpg");


    return 0;


}
```

I am not sure of where is the problem

Comment: how did you install opencv ? are you sure to run 2.4.9 ? the cv::String in the signature seems to hint at 3.0, where you have to additionally include / link the imcodecs module

Comment: similar to @Otantic's answer below, INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include  (without opencv or opencv2)

Answer (score 0):

includepath must show opencv and opencv2.just like that:

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:\\opencv-2.4.6.1\\build-msvc2012\\install\\include
 LIBS+=-LC:\\opencv-2.4.6.1\\build-msvc2012\\install\\lib \
 -lopencv_calib3d246d \
 -lopencv_contrib246d \
 -lopencv_core246d \
 -lopencv_features2d246d \
 -lopencv_flann246d \
```

lıbs must show .lib file

Answer (score 0):

Your code builds and runs just fine for me on a somewhat antique stock ubuntu 12.10 with opencv 2.3 from the distribution packages.

It picks up a cv::imread(std::string const &, int) from libopencv_highgui.